# 'Stretching' a div to the edge of a browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an absolutely positioned header with background image. I would like both divs (also with background image) "stretch" from my header to the left and right edges of the users browser without needing a scrollbar. How could I do this? Thanks!

Comment: background image stretch using css? which one is other div? then header?

Answer (score 2):

Use `width: 100%;` and set the position to `left: 0px;`.

Check out: http://jsfiddle.net/joshcomley/ma26B/

Answer (score 0):

THis is normally done with `width:100%` on CSS. I mean, browser nuances notwithstanding.

Answer (score 0):

See normally a HTML page have the margins set to `5px` or something else. But if you want your `div` element to be stretched up to the both edges do this --

```
<html>
      <head>
            <style>
                   body { margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; background: #555; }
                   div.element { width: 100%; display: block; background: #000; color: #fff; padding: 5px 5px;}  
            </style> 
      </head>
      <body>
             <div class="element">Stretched to the both edges of you HTML page!</div> 
      </body> 
</html>
```

That's all just copy and past the above code in your HTML page and execute and see the magic!

I hope this would help!

Comment: And by the way if you want to stretch your header `div` please try doing it with the `table` element. Because `table` element will let you to have a complete frame for your website; from header to footer and your middle content. If you want some tips on it please let me know. For related code copy the HTML section in this fiddle----
http://jsfiddle.net/divinemamgai/vZepT/

Hope you would like this.

Comment: the thing is that there are 3 divs. one is in the center of a page and is 900px wide (lets name it "centerdiv") . The other two need to stretch sideways from the centerdiv to the edge of a browser window. the leftsidediv has to reach the left side of the browser and the rightsidediv the right side.